# Input parameters validation and response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, validation

I want to validate operation parameters sent from the client (using IParameterInspector) in my service and in case of wrong parameter input I would like to send response code as a part of the response object instead of throwing fault exception.
Please let me know how I can achieve this.

**UPDATE** :
If it is not possible with IParameterInspector, what other options you will suggest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspector intercepts calls to service operations and performs logic for validating the parameters passed to that operation. If the parameters are found invalid the actual service operation never gets executed, and the only way to notify client is exception (better be part of FaultContract).

Answer (score 0):

do you use  wcf ? if yes you can use FualtException of Wcf

Comment: Yes it is WCF, but as I said I don't want to throw Exception.